# Android install apk without asking user permission

Tags: java, android, android-intent, apk, android-download-manager

I am building a App for kiosk mode purposes. The device is not rooted. 
The app is the device administrator (android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN) . I want the app to be able to download and direct install other apks onto the tablet without asking for permission.

At moment I am using Android DownloadManager to download the apk:
then:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
                                DownloadManagerActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

To install the apk. But this bring a popup for confirmation.
is theer another away to direct install the apk after it has been downloaded?
Thanks

**update**:

I came across this post:
https://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/

But it does not work and it very limited.

Comment: One way is there to achieve your requirement. in Android M they provide the installation without asking any permission

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to install the APK without the popup confirmation. This is a by-design security feature. Some phone vendors like Samsung offer options like SAFE or KNOX to allow that installing without a prompt, but it requires additional permissions and these technologies are not available across all android devices.

Comment: thanks buddy. I thought by having my app as DEVICE_ADMIN I would be able to do that

Comment: Unfortunately, even that doesn't give you access to install applications without permission. It's why a lot of MDM software always has to prompt the user on non-samsung devices, for example.

Comment: If you have the System/OS SHA key you can install with out prompt

Comment: @RaviGadipudi could you please expand your answer. thanks

Comment: OEM/Google will have a SHA Key to build the OS. If that the same key is used to build an App, that will get all system permissions.

Comment: In a normal application distribution setting though, @RaviGadipudi's solution will not be possible.